# Moving directories that names end in - number matching a list.txt file

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting

Graphic of Folder Structure :

[image]

I am very new to advanced shell commands and scripting. I have fundamental  terminal knowledge but have never attempted to create an automation like this before. A pure newbie.

I have simplified my goal in this post but the actual project would be for a few thousand folders.

Basically I have a Source and Destination folder.
The Source folder has directories with the prefix “Car” followed by “three numbers”

I have a text file called list.txt in the Source folder which is a list of “three numbers” per line.

I would like to either write a command or a script that will find directories and read the list. If the last three digits in the directory name match the three digits in the list. I would like to move the matching folders to the Destination folder.

I have read a variety of methods using find, -exec mv, xargs, “while IFS read” and I really don't know the best way to approach this. I am just getting started and was hoping someone on this forum could chime in and not beat me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script to run in the parent directory of `Destination` and `Source` (`.` in your picture):

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r l; do
   mv "Source/Car$l/" Destination/.
done < Source/list.txt
```

This script reads `Source/list.txt` line by line. For each line `$l` it tries to move the directory named `Source/Car$l` to `Destination/.`.

The dot pathname component in `Destination/.` is a trick in case `Destination` does not exist. If `Destination` did not exist then the first `mv "Source/Car…/" Destination/` would rename `Source/Car…/` to `Destination/` instead of putting it inside `Destination/`. The dot makes a difference: if the target is `Destination/.` and `Destination/` does not exist then our `mv` command(s) will exit with an error.

The script is *dumb*, it does not perform any sanity check on what it reads from `Source/list.txt`. E.g. if a line is `001/../../../../../../../../../../home/roco/.ssh` then the script will possibly move your `~/.ssh/` directory to `Destination/`. If there is an empty line then the script will try to move `Source/Car/`. If the last line is incomplete then it won't get to `mv` (see [*Why does this `while` loop not recognize the last line?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482517/108618)).

Comment: Why `Destination/.` instead of `.`?

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I read an article that was very similar but it did not have the $1 which was the piece I was missing. I will run a few tests but I am sure this will work for the task. I will also review your comments about the possible unintended actions due to issues with the list.txt file.

Comment: Also wanted to say thank your for including the additional details. I ran a few test replacing mv with echo and removing the destination. You were correct and identifying the last line of list.txt will not be picked up if there is not followed by a return. This is a great learning exercise

Comment: @terdon Because of how I interpreted "I would like to move the matching folders to the Destination folder".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski but is there any difference between `mv foo bar/` and `mv foo bar/.` ? They should be completely equivalent, right?

Comment: @terdon You asked "why `Destination/.` instead of `.`?", but now you're continuing as if "why `Destination/.` instead of `Destination`?". If `bar` does not exist then `mv foo bar/` will rename `foo` to `bar` (if `foo` itself is a directory). But `mv foo bar/.` will not rename `foo` to `bar`, it can only move `foo` into existing `bar/`; I think it's a portable "equivalent" of `mv -t bar foo` which also cannot rename `foo`. In the question `Destination` exists, but I write also for future users with similar problems and sometimes I like to include interesting trivia.

Comment: Oh ugh, sorry, yes. I should have asked "Why `Destination/.` instead of `Destination`?", my bad. That's what I meant. And yes, you're absolutely right and that's a clever trick to handle cases where the target dir doesn't exist. Nice! Thanks for explaining. And I now see you have a whole paragraph explaining it which I somehow managed to completely miss. Sorry :/